# Using regex to replace matches in place

Tags: c++, regex, string, boost

I'm attempting to do a certain type of "string expansion", wherein I replace keys with strings from a database. The format of the tag is `{$<key>}`.

I'm using `<regex>` to try and get this done but I've run into a bit of a logistical problem. I want to be able to replace the strings in one pass, but modifying the string (`s`) can invalidate the iterators found in the `smatch` objects.

Here is more or less what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, string> m;

    m.insert(make_pair("severity", "absolute"));
    m.insert(make_pair("experience", "nightmare"));

    string s = "This is an {$severity} {$experience}!";
    static regex e("\\{\\$(.*?)\\}");
    sregex_iterator next(s.begin(), s.end(), e);
    sregex_iterator end;

    for (; next != end; ++next)
    {
        auto m_itr = m.find(next->str(1));

        if (m_itr == m.end())
        {
            continue;
        }

        //TODO: replace expansion tags with strings somehow?

        cout << (*next).str(0) << ":" << m_itr->second << endl;
    }
}
```

The desired end result is that `s` reads:

```
"This is an absolute nightmare!"
```

I know that I could perform this type of thing in multiple passes, but that seems a bit brutish.

I read somewhere that `boost::regex` had some variation of `regex_replace` that allowed a custom replacement function in this form:

```
regex_replace(std::string&, regex, std::string(const smatch&))
```

However, my current version `(1.55)` has no such thing.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

P.S. I can use either `boost` or `std` for this, whichever works!

Comment: Are you sure the regex itself is correct?

Comment: perhaps related: [compiling-a-simple-parser-with-boost-spirit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404558/shortened/9405546#9405546), [replacing-pieces-of-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241897/shortened/17243219#17243219), [how-to-expand-environment-variables-in-ini-files-using-boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112494/shortened/17126962#17126962) and perhaps most interestingly [fast-multi-replacement-into-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571578/shortened/22571753#22571753)

Answer (score 1):

So, in addition to the comment I made 8 hours ago:

> perhaps related: [Compiling a simple parser with Boost.Spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404558/compiling-a-simple-parser-with-boost-spirit/9405546#9405546), [replacing pieces of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241897/replacing-pieces-of-string/17243219#17243219), [How to expand environment variables in .ini files using Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112494/how-to-expand-environment-variables-in-ini-files-using-boost/17126962#17126962) and perhaps most interestingly [Fast multi-replacement into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571578/fast-multi-replacement-into-string/22571753#22571753)

I saw room for one more approach. What if... you needed to do many many replacements based on the same text template, but using different replacement maps?

Since I've recently discovered how [Boost ICL can be useful in mapping regions of input strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397514/randomly-selecting-specific-subsequence-from-string/28401533?s=1|0.0000#28401533), I wanted to do the same here.

I made things pretty generic, and employed Spirit to do the analyis (`study`):

```
template <
    typename InputRange,
    typename It = typename boost::range_iterator<InputRange const>::type,
    typename IntervalSet = boost::icl::interval_set<It> >
IntervalSet study(InputRange const& input) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    It first(begin(input)), last(end(input));

    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    using boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek;

    IntervalSet variables;

    parse(first, last, *seek [ raw [ "{$" >> +alnum >> "}" ] ], variables);

    return variables;
}
```

As you can see, instead of doing any replacements, we just return a `interval_set<It>` so we know where our variables are. This is now the "wisdom" that can be used to perform the replacements from a map of replacement strings:

```
template <
    typename InputRange,
    typename Replacements,
    typename OutputIterator,
    typename StudyMap,
    typename It = typename boost::range_iterator<InputRange const>::type
>
OutputIterator perform_replacements(InputRange const& input, Replacements const& m, StudyMap const& wisdom, OutputIterator out) 
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    It current(begin(input));

    for (auto& replace : wisdom)
    {
        It l(lower(replace)),
        u(upper(replace));

        if (current < l)
            out = std::copy(current, l, out);

        auto match = m.find({l+2, u-1});
        if (match == m.end())
            out = std::copy(l, u, out);
        else
            out = std::copy(begin(match->second), end(match->second), out);

        current = u;
    }

    if (current!=end(input))
        out = std::copy(current, end(input), out);
    return out;
}
```

Now, a simple test program would be like this:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string const input = "This {$oops} is an {$severity} {$experience}!\n";
    auto const wisdom = study(input);

    cout << "Wisdom: ";
    for(auto& entry : wisdom)
        cout << entry;

    auto m = map<string, string> {
            { "severity",   "absolute"  },
            { "OOPS",       "REALLY"    },
            { "experience", "nightmare" },
        };

    ostreambuf_iterator<char> out(cout);
    out = '\n';

    perform_replacements(input, m, wisdom, out);

    // now let's use a case insensitive map, still with the same "study"
    map<string, string, ci_less> im { m.begin(), m.end() };
    im["eXperience"] = "joy";

    perform_replacements(input, im, wisdom, out);
}
```

Prints

```
Wisdom: {$oops}{$severity}{$experience}
This {$oops} is an absolute nightmare!
This REALLY is an absolute joy!
```

You could call it for a input string literal, using an `unordered_map` for the replacements etc. You could omit the `wisdom`, in which case the implementation will study it on-the-fly.

### Full Program

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3a03d5364f0b9a4)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/icl/interval_set.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template <typename It>
        struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<icl::discrete_interval<It>, It, void> {
            template <typename ... T> static void call(It b, It e, icl::discrete_interval<It>& out) {
                out = icl::discrete_interval<It>::right_open(b, e);
            }
        };
} } }

template <
    typename InputRange,
    typename It = typename boost::range_iterator<InputRange const>::type,
    typename IntervalSet = boost::icl::interval_set<It> >
IntervalSet study(InputRange const& input) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    It first(begin(input)), last(end(input));

    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    using boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek;

    IntervalSet variables;    
    parse(first, last, *seek [ raw [ "{$" >> +alnum >> "}" ] ], variables);

    return variables;
}

template <
    typename InputRange,
    typename Replacements,
    typename OutputIterator,
    typename StudyMap,
    typename It = typename boost::range_iterator<InputRange const>::type
>
OutputIterator perform_replacements(InputRange const& input, Replacements const& m, StudyMap const& wisdom, OutputIterator out) 
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    It current(begin(input));

    for (auto& replace : wisdom)
    {
        It l(lower(replace)),
           u(upper(replace));

        if (current < l)
            out = std::copy(current, l, out);

        auto match = m.find({l+2, u-1});
        if (match == m.end())
            out = std::copy(l, u, out);
        else
            out = std::copy(begin(match->second), end(match->second), out);

        current = u;
    }

    if (current!=end(input))
        out = std::copy(current, end(input), out);
    return out;
}

template <
    typename InputRange,
    typename Replacements,
    typename OutputIterator,
    typename It = typename boost::range_iterator<InputRange const>::type
>
OutputIterator perform_replacements(InputRange const& input, Replacements const& m, OutputIterator out) {
    return perform_replacements(input, m, study(input), out);
}

// for demo program
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
struct ci_less {
    template <typename S>
    bool operator() (S const& a, S const& b) const {
        return boost::lexicographical_compare(a, b, boost::is_iless());
    }
};

namespace boost { namespace icl {
    template <typename It>
        static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, discrete_interval<It> const& i) {
            return os << make_iterator_range(lower(i), upper(i));
        }
} }

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string const input = "This {$oops} is an {$severity} {$experience}!\n";
    auto const wisdom = study(input);

    cout << "Wisdom: ";
    for(auto& entry : wisdom)
        cout << entry;

    auto m = map<string, string> {
            { "severity",   "absolute"  },
            { "OOPS",       "REALLY"    },
            { "experience", "nightmare" },
        };

    ostreambuf_iterator<char> out(cout);
    out = '\n';

    perform_replacements(input, m, wisdom, out);

    // now let's use a case insensitive map, still with the same "study"
    map<string, string, ci_less> im { m.begin(), m.end() };
    im["eXperience"] = "joy";

    perform_replacements(input, im, wisdom, out);
}
```

### In - place operation

As long as you make sure that the replacements strings are always shorter than the `{$pattern}` strings (or equal length), you can simply call this function with `input.begin()` as the output iterator.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4fbf351df4a158a)</kbd>**

```
string input1 = "This {$803525c8-3ce4-423a-ad25-cc19bbe8422a} is an {$efa72abf-fe96-4983-b373-a35f70551e06} {$8a10abaa-cc0d-47bd-a8e1-34a8aa0ec1ef}!\n",
       input2 = input1;

auto m = map<string, string> {
        { "efa72abf-fe96-4983-b373-a35f70551e06", "absolute"  },
        { "803525C8-3CE4-423A-AD25-CC19BBE8422A", "REALLY"    },
        { "8a10abaa-cc0d-47bd-a8e1-34a8aa0ec1ef", "nightmare" },
    };

input1.erase(perform_replacements(input1, m, input1.begin()), input1.end());

map<string, string, ci_less> im { m.begin(), m.end() };
im["8a10abaa-cc0d-47bd-a8e1-34a8aa0ec1ef"] = "joy";

input2.erase(perform_replacements(input2, im, input2.begin()), input2.end());

std::cout << input1
          << input2;
```

Prints

```
This {$803525c8-3ce4-423a-ad25-cc19bbe8422a} is an absolute nightmare!
This REALLY is an absolute joy!
```

Note that you can (obviously) not re-use the same "wisdom" on the same input template again because it will have been modified.

Comment: Added an actual example of in-place replacement **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98717004d71b1478)** (no runtime checking of lengths)